# Matching on content-type in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, content-type, mime

I know I can use `FilesMatch "\.html$"` like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.html$">
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header set Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

But this won't help if the html is delivered as a SEO friendly URL (like wordpress does), right?

I there a way to match on content-type equals `text/html`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on Apache 2.4.10 or later, you can use `expr=` as

```
Header set Pragma "public" "expr=%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m#text/html#"
Header set Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate" "expr=%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m#text/html#"
```

See the documentation and examples on [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) and [expr](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html).

Comment: Hmh, does not seem to be working. My `Content-Type` header is `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`. My line in htaccess is `Header set X-TEST "Just testing" "expr=resp('Content-Type') == 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'"`. 

Only if I remove the `"expr=resp('Content-Type') == 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'"`the `X-TEST` header gets inserted. 

Also I noticed that `=~` is not working as it [should](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html#binop). 

I am on apache 2.4.12

Comment: Debug and check the value of `Header set X-TEST "expr=resp('Content-Type')"` or `Header set X-TEST "expr=%{resp:Content-Type}"`.

Comment: I've added `Header set X-TEST-CT "expr=resp('Content-Type')"` and `Header set X-TEST-EXPR "expr=%{resp:Content-Type}"`. Then the response has an `X-TEST-CR` header with `X-TEST-CT: "resp('Content-Type')"`, and *no* X-TEST-EXPR header. Seems like `expr` is not evaluated?

Comment: Got it after finally reading the documentation! I updated the answer accordingly. It was `"expr=%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m#text/html#"`. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Thanks for getting back with the updates. Just goes to show how the official docs give you 10 ways of doing the same thing but often lack the more important information on what works when. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple content-types to one expression? E.g. if I want to target text/html and image/svg in that one expression?